# Processing TIF images with Marshal.Copy ends in a Fatal Error

Tags: vb.net, marshalling, fatal-error

I have a function that inserts one image into another byte-wise:

```
    Public Function InsertPIP(ByRef BmpSrc As Bitmap, ByRef BmpTgt As Bitmap, InsertPoint As Point, Optional bpp As Int16 = 1) As Bitmap
        If BmpSrc.Width + InsertPoint.X <= BmpTgt.Width And BmpSrc.Height + InsertPoint.Y <= BmpTgt.Height Then
            Try

                Dim DataSrc As Imaging.BitmapData = BmpSrc.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, BmpSrc.Width, BmpSrc.Height), Imaging.ImageLockMode.[WriteOnly], Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
                Dim BytesSrc As Byte() = New Byte(DataSrc.Height * DataSrc.Stride) {}

                If VerboseLevel >= 3 Then LW.WriteLine("InsertPIP:          Stride=" & DataSrc.Stride.ToString & "    Scan=" & DataSrc.Scan0.ToInt64 & "    DataSRC.Size=" & DataSrc.Width & "x" & DataSrc.Height & "    BytesSRC.len=" & BytesSrc.Length.ToString & "     Height*Stride=" & (DataSrc.Height * DataSrc.Stride).ToString)
                Marshal.Copy(DataSrc.Scan0, BytesSrc, 0, BytesSrc.Length)
                '^^^^^^^^^^^^ ERROR OCURS HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^

                Dim DataTgt As Imaging.BitmapData = BmpTgt.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, BmpTgt.Width, BmpTgt.Height), Imaging.ImageLockMode.[WriteOnly], Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
                Dim BytesTgt As Byte() = New Byte(DataTgt.Height * DataTgt.Stride - 1) {}
                Marshal.Copy(DataTgt.Scan0, BytesTgt, 0, BytesTgt.Length)

                BytesTgt = InsertPictureIntoPicture(BytesSrc, BytesTgt, BmpSrc.Width, 1, New Rectangle(InsertPoint.X, InsertPoint.Y, BmpSrc.Width, BmpSrc.Height), DataSrc.Stride * 8 / bpp, DataTgt.Stride * 8 / bpp)
                Marshal.Copy(BytesTgt, 0, DataTgt.Scan0, BytesTgt.Length)

                BmpSrc.UnlockBits(DataSrc)
                BmpTgt.UnlockBits(DataTgt)

            Catch ex As Exception
                If VerboseLevel >= 3 Then LW.WriteLine("InsertPIP ERROR:  " & ex.Message & vbCrLf)
            End Try
            Return BmpTgt
        Else
            LW.WriteLine("WARNING: Inserting bitmap into bitmap: Source doesn't fit the target.   BmpSrc=[" & BmpSrc.Width & "," & BmpSrc.Height & "]     BmpTgt=[" & BmpTgt.Width & "," & BmpTgt.Height & "]     pt=[" & InsertPoint.X & "," & InsertPoint.Y & "]")
            Return BmpTgt
        End If
    End Function
```

It's been working for more than a year fine in 99+% cases. But some rare images throw cause a fatal error on line `Marshal.Copy(...)` ("*Fatal Error Detected - unable to continue. Unhandled operating system exception: e0434352"*). I am trying to find the cause of the problem but:

- debugger seems to me useless, it just says `System.AccessViolationException` and `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException` with no other details
- `try-catch` does not catch the fatal error
- trying to see the print the inputs didn't help me:

  InsertPIP:          Stride=512    Scan=2562876506112    DataSRC.Size=4088x712    BytesSRC.len=364545     Height*Stride=364544

---

EDIT: I tried to isolate it into standalone application and debug there and no I get little bit more detailed exception message (and what I expected):

```
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
```

---

I generate all the TIF images, they're generated with the same methods and they have all `PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed`.

Affected Image:
[image]

I haven't been able to find much on the internet, suggestions apprectiated. If I can improve my question, please let me know how.

Link to the original TIF image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xTIQi5M9UxK7A98992W3PUNMOmODP8p2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Confirm that all TIFF images are CCITT4. What format and pixel format is the Image that's being inserted? Post details related to the Images you're working with -- You should remove `ByRef` from the parameters and generate a copy of the destination Image, then return the modified copy.

Comment: @Jimi I generate them all using the same methods. They're all 1 bit per pixel (`PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed`). I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong with `ByRef`, but I did that on purpose to not overflow memmory, since the images might get resolution like 80Kx50K (they're plots up to A0 in plot quality). Anyway, this should not affect the `Marshal.Copy`, right? Maybe you thought I'm returning the same thing, but that's not the case - I return `BmpTgt`, which is created after the line with first `Marshal.Copy`, where the function crashes.

Comment: @Jimi As for `Imports` - I'd love to :-). But my module is executed via a CAD/CAM system, which stubbornly and somehow randomly refuses to respect some `Import` statements. So I got into habbit (for this project only) to reference them from globally imported namesapces. But I can modify it in the provided code, if it helps.

Comment: GDI+ cannot generate a Bitmap of `80,000 * 50,000`. A Bitmap must occupy contiguous space in your memory slice and the maximum of each dimension cannot exceed 65530 pixels. The overall memory space is then *variable* and you have no control over it. Your Bitmap could generate an exception when it reaches 500Mpx or 700Mpx. `80,000 * 50,000` is `4,000,000,000` bytes min. (assuming 1 byte per color). If you need to handle Images of that size, the Bitmap class is not your thing. You need a completely different library.

Comment: @Jimi, yes GDI cannot do that, it cannot even work with 1bpp images to keep the size meaningful. That is why I'm avoiding GDI+ and doing it bit-wise with my methods. All is working fine for 1 year, there's just one "small" image (4088x712px), a component of a larger image, where the error occurs. My guess is, that in that case I don't have for some reason properly sized `ByteArray` or I do some other mistake related to bit operations, which only causes error when some rare combinaitons of picture size or stride vs byte array happen.

Comment: You have Bitmap objects there, so yes, you're working with GDI+, so the size of the Bitmaps counts. `Bitmap.LockBits()` is still GDI+. Not clear why you're returning a a Bitmap that is passed `ByRef` -- I don't know what `InsertPictureIntoPicture()` is doing, that method overwrites the `BytesTgt` array -- To tell you what's wrong with the Images that generate an exception, you should post those Images.

Comment: It's not like GDI+ doesn't work completely. The problem is, that some of it's methods cannot work with indexed formats, thus cannot work with 1bpp images. The smallest possible format will cause the picture to be in memmory at least 16 times bigger (if I remember it correcly), which is obviously huge difference for large drawings. `InsertPictureIntoPicture()` does some byte operations, but I don't get there, the code crashes on `Marshal.Copy`. I now clearly indicated that in the code above, sorry I didn't do this earlier. I'll think how I could share affected image.

Comment: You have posted a PNG image.

Comment: @Jimi You're right, I inserted TIF, but apparently it was converted into PNG.  I will try to link it from some cloud.

Comment: Link to orginal TIF added.

Comment: I have no problem locking that Image or to `Marshal.Copy()` the data to a buffer. I suggest to remove all `ByRef` stuff (which has no use here and can only cause trouble), make sure the Image is not attached to a FileStream, i.e., load it as `dim tifImage = CType(Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([The TIFF path])), true, false), Bitmap)` if it's saved on disk. The `ImageLockMode` should be `ImageLockMode.ReadWrite`, but it doesn't affect the first `.LockBit()` call.

Comment: I see one obvious bug, BytesTgt is too small by 1 byte.  How that could cause the AV is not clear to me, can't see what InsertPictureIntoPicture() does and what DataTgt.Stride * 8 / bpp might mean.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for pointing that out, I'm not sure if this should cause the problem, but I definitely investigate that. If its really short by 1 byte, in theory, it could cause 25% probability to not fit into the bytearray, but I get the error only in 1 of few hundred cases. I also think the -1 is there, because bytearray is 0-based. I'll dive in on Monday.

Comment: @HansPassant I've looked into it, the `-1` is in the 2nd `ByteArray` bellow the place where the program crashes and removing it doesn't help. Nither it caused any problems until now. However, I think it shouldn't be there, the length of the array should be just `Stride * Height`. So +1 for the comment.